# How do docker run commands translate to docker compose files?

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

The official docker image for MySQL 5.7 sets strict SQL modes. I understand that one can change the modes when using *docker run* like this:

```
 docker run [...] -d mysql --sql-modes="modes"
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to change the compose file to reflect this change. I tried adding the following snippet to the compose file:

```
 command: --sql-modes="modes"
```

but that doesn't seem to be the right way of doing this.

I assume this is a very trivial question but I'm rather new to docker, hopefully someone can give me a hint.

EDIT:

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepass
       MYSQL_DATABASE: db1
       MYSQL_USER: user1
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: somepass1

volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

After "environment", I tried adding one of these two lines:

```
 command: --sql-modes=""
 command: mysql --sql-modes=""
```

If I did so, the container wouldn't even properly start. If I remove the command line, the container starts properly.

Comment: Tried `command: mysql --sql-modes="modes"`?

Comment: Does your approach not work, or does it work but you just think it is not the correct way of solving the problem?

Comment: @t.niese it doesn't work at all, it seems MySQL is not started in the container

Comment: @jonnix I'll try that, thanks

Comment: For the official [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) image `command:` should be the correct way to add arguments. Those are appended to the entry point, which is [mysql/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh). So I would guess there should be a problem somewhere else.  And it should not matter if you write `command: mysqld --sql-modes="modes"` or  `command: --sql-modes="modes"` Due to the lines 5-8 in the entrypoint file. Where `mysqld` is prepend if `command` starts with an option.

Comment: @t.niese I added more information to my question. Do you see an issue there?

Comment: @jonnix Unfortunately, adding the command line you mentioned did not seem to do the trick.

Comment: Should be `--sql-mode`.

Comment: Thanks Jonnix, I realized this after t.niese made me aware of the entrypoint file and that the arguments in "command" are really just appended to running mysqld. So I went to check the the MySQL documentation and yes, damn typo! :-) Thanks to you both for the valuable input.

Comment: @vic As a note `mysql` is the client `mysqld` is the server. So if you want to write the full command to compose it has to be `command: mysqld` followed by the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Once more, the lesson is, don't be copy pasting code from forums or boards without understanding what it means..

In this specific case, I consulted the issues page on Github for the MySQL docker container, specifically [issue 112](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/112). It's stated there, by a collaborator of the image no less, that the container can be run with the argument `--sql-modes="modes"`.

Well, that's false. The correct argument is `--sql-mode="modes"`, i.e. without the s after mode.

Thanks to Jonnix and t.niese for pointing me in the right direction, I have a better understanding of the command directive now.

Comment: You never should just copy and past something you read without verifying and understanding what it does. In the best case it works, in a not so good case it just fails and in the worst case it does something harmful. And that is especially true for docker containers or composer files. If you e.g. mount the root of your system to a docker container that container can read and write to your whole system without knowing any of your user passwords.

Comment: I generally agree I just couldn't wrap my head around what the command directive does and how it should be used, even though I read the docker compose documentation about it. It was really your hint at lines 5-8 in the entrypoint.sh that made things a lot clearer for me. Other than that I'm quite comfortable running containers though I'm more experienced with LXC than docker.